# pass data from input text [post method] MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to insert data into my DB in ASP MVC. I have successfully inserted into my DB. here is the code for the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.admin_privilage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.admin_privilage)
                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

and the controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createuser (User collection)
    {
List<object> lst = new List<object>();
            lst.Add(collection.username);
            lst.Add(collection.admin_privilage);
object[] allitems = lst.ToArray();
int output = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into USER (username,admin_privilage) values (@p0,@p1)", allitems);
return View();

}
```

What I want to ask is, in my view is using customize input text and label as follow:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="col-form-label">名前:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="addadmin" name="admin">
                            <label for="admin" class="col-form-label">Admin</label>
                        </div>
    </div>
                    </div>
```

How can I capture the input parameter from users and pass it in Controller? so it can be inserted to my database as well.

Comment: You can use `name` attribute for textbox & `Request.Form` (or `BindAttribute` in POST) if you not want to use strongly-typed viewmodel. But I recommend using `TextBoxFor` and a viewmodel to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using the same model.name as in html form control id and name attribute like:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username" class="col-form-label">名前:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" **id="username" name="username"**>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="checkbox" **id="admin_privilage" name="admin_privilage"**>
<label for="admin_privilage" class="col-form-label">Admin</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: my checkbox value is always 0. do you know why?

Comment: you can add value attribute like  `value=" "` on checkbox control